# Enabling WIFI and Bluetooth with Intel® Wireless-AC 9560

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, iwlwifi

I'm new to this site and this OS "Ubuntu"

so I have problems with wifi and bluetooth..

I just check the logs and finally think the problem is related to firmware..

```
dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.819550] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 34.0.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.833065] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x338
[    7.900012] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[    7.900015] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[    7.900016] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device config registers:
[    7.900050] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 34f08086 00100406 02800030 00800010 17114004 00000060 00000000 00000000
[    7.900051] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00348086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 000001ff
[    7.900052] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[    7.900086] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 00489008 00000040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    7.900087] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000011 0c040005 00000332 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 001f0040
[    7.900106] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[    7.900110] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    7.913089] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0x0bad1122]
[    7.925547] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

```
dmesg|grep -i firmware
[    0.261195] pci 0000:00:1f.5: BAR 0: trying firmware assignment [mem 0xfe010000-0xfe010fff]
[    0.827494] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
[    1.719365] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x4d5f02)
[    1.997497] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 34.0.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.313386] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    2.314629] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for intel/ibt-19-32-1.sfi failed with error -2
[    2.314631] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file (-2)
[    2.316386] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    2.316393] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for intel/ibt-19-32-1.sfi failed with error -2
[    2.316395] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file (-2)
[    3.349840] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[    7.136131] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to load firmware chunk!
```

```
rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

my laptop model is hp  15-cs3012tx and version of Ubuntu is 16.04 LTS
I just searched of my adapter model, it says

Intel® Wireless-AC 9560 802.11a/b/g/n/ac (2x2) Wi-Fi® and Bluetooth® 5 Combo

so I just downloaded intel ac 9560 firmware to install

```
1. OVERVIEW

The file iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode provided in this package must be 
present on your system in order for the Intel Wireless WiFi Link
AGN driver for Linux (iwlagn) to operate on your system.

The "-2" in the filename reflects an interface/architecture version number.
It will change only when changes in new uCode releases make the new uCode
incompatible with earlier drivers.

On adapter initialization, and at varying times during the uptime of 
the adapter, the microcode is loaded into the memory on the network 
adapter.  The microcode provides the low level MAC features including 
radio control and high precision timing events (backoff, transmit, 
etc.) while also providing varying levels of packet filtering which can 
be used to keep the host from having to handle packets that are not of 
interest given the current operating mode of the device.

2. INSTALLATION

The iwlagn driver will look for the file iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode using the 
kernel's firmware_loader infrastructure.  In order to function 
correctly, you need to have this support enabled in your kernel.  When 
you configure the kernel, you can find this option in the following 
location:

        Device Drivers ->
                Generic Driver Options ->
                        Hotplug firmware loading support


You can determine if your kernel currently has firmware loader support 
by looking for the CONFIG_FW_LOADER definition on your kernel's 
.config.

In addition to having the firmware_loader support in your kernel, you 
must also have a working hotplug and udev infrastructure configured.  
The steps for installing and configuring hotplug and udev are very 
distribution specific. 

Once you have the firmware loader in place (or if you aren't sure and 
you just want to try things to see if it works), you need to install 
the microcode file into the appropriate location.

Where that appropriate location is depends (again) on your system 
distribution.  You can typically find this location by looking in the 
hotplug configuration file for your distro:

    % grep \"^FIRMWARE_DIR\" /etc/hotplug/firmware.agent

This should give you output like:

    FIRMWARE_DIR=/lib/firmware

If it lists more than one directory, you only need to put the 
microcode in one of them.  In the above example, installation is 
simply:

    % cp iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode /lib/firmware

You can now load the driver (see the INSTALL and README.iwlwifi provided with
the iwlwifi package for information on building and using that driver.)
```

this is the attached document with the firmware file

I typed the command and it showed like this

```
grep \"^FIRMWARE_DIR\" /etc/hotplug/firmware.agent
grep: /etc/hotplug/firmware.agent: No such file or directory
```

but in the document it was supposed to be like this

```
% grep \"^FIRMWARE_DIR\" /etc/hotplug/firmware.agent

This should give you output like:

    FIRMWARE_DIR=/lib/firmware
```

I can't install this firmware with the way above..
and I think this 9650 device is related to wifi and bluetooth..

could someone pls give me a hand to install this firmware..?

thank you for your hand in advance

edit) I also included logs with command `dmesg|grep -i firmware`

Comment: So which is the Ubuntu release you're using? Your description says 16.04, and the tag says 14.04. One is still supported and the other is not.

Comment: Ubuntu server and desktop releases use a *yy.mm* format, so 16.04 means the 2016-April release of Ubuntu, which comes with 5 years of free standard support, 14.04 standard support ended 2019-April (5 years from 14.04) so is now off-topic and only supported by Canonical through Ubuntu Advantage.  Yes there are specialist releases that have *yy* format but most people use server & desktop releases.

Comment: @Kurankat I am sorry for including wrong tag... I'm using 16.04 version so mine is supported one..

Comment: @guiverc I'm using 16.04 version so that means this standard support ends 2021-April.. I don't know why this thing happens to me..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing a more modern version of Ubuntu? It's not uncommon for newer hardware to not have drivers available in older releases, and 16.04 is only supported for 1 more year.

There are a couple of possible options:. You could try a more modern version, 18.04 or wait a month and install 20.04, which will have the more modern kernel and be supported for 5 years (until April 2025).

You also could try installing the [Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) kernel, which will have more modern drivers available and might solve your problem (HWE uses the 4.15 kernel, rather than 4.04 which came with 16.04).

To do so, do as recommended in the link above:

`sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04`

But ultimately you may have a better experience in a modern laptop running a more modern OS (I'd personally install 19.04 and upgrade to 20.04).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! xD I tried Hardware Enablement Stack and finally got the sound back! but still I can't enable WIFI and Bluetooth functions.. I should use 16.04 version because the instructor told us to use that.. the reason might be related to ROS but I'm not sure about that.. Installing newest version of Ubuntu is the best solution I think.. but I can't do this thing due to class. After finishing this class, I must install the newer version to solve this problem. Thank you for your answer and have a nice day!!